# ConstraintKind inconsistency?

Tags: haskell, constraint-kinds

I want to use custom constraints to help curb combinatorial explosion:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class DifferentTypes a b
type DifferentTypes3 a b c = (DifferentTypes a b, DifferentTypes b c, DifferentTypes a c)
```

---

When I use my custom constraint, this code fails to compile:

```
class Foo a
class Bar a
instance (DifferentTypes3 a b c, Bar a, Bar b, Bar c) => Foo (a, b, c)
```

---

But when I instead manually write out my constraints, it compiles:

```
class Foo a
class Bar a
instance (DifferentTypes a b, DifferentTypes b c, DifferentTypes a c, Bar a, Bar b, Bar c) => Foo (a, b, c)
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: You will need to switch on `UndecidableInstances` for that. constraints are substituted later than you would expect.

Comment: Despite the fact that `UndecidableInstances` seems to be a workaround, I'd call this a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. I filed a bug here http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8359

Answer (score 0):

With [GHC ticket #8359](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8359) fixed, your original code (using `ConstraintKinds`) now typechecks as expected without `UndecidableInstances`.